# Enter the quotation marks in a JSON attribute without including the escape quotation marks

Tags: json

I wanted to ask if there is a way to put quotation marks in a JSON string without using the escape quotes because I should add too many! Thank you for your response and excuse my English but I am Italian! Below is the JSON file I talk about

`{
    "nome": "Progetto5",
    "username": "Zlatan",
    "pro": " {"cells":[{"type":"uml.Class","name":["prova"],"attributes":["+ 
       speremo:int","+ speremo:int","+ speremo:int"],"methods":[],"position": 
       {"x":200,"y":300},"size":
       {"width":160,"height":100},"angle":0,"id":"fd1bed50-eaad-4e36-8ab4-
       874a58a76d81","z":1,"attrs":{".uml-class-name-rect":
       {"height":40,"transform":"translate(0,0)"},".uml-class-attrs-rect":
       {"height":80,"transform":"translate(0,40)"},".uml-class-methods-rect":
       {"height":20,"transform":"translate(0,120)"},".uml-class-name-text":
       {"text":"prova"},".uml-class-attrs-text":{"text":"+ speremo:int\n+ 
       speremo:int\n+ speremo:int"},".uml-class-methods-text":{"text":""}}},
       {"type":"uml.Class","name":["prova"],"attributes":["+ speremo:int","+ 
       speremo:int","+ speremo:int"],"methods":[],"position":
       {"x":200,"y":300},"size":
       {"width":160,"height":100},"angle":0,"id":"24eb82fd-18bd-4702-8565-5"
}`

Comment: Sorry but this is my first question, the json file has 3 attributes: "nome", "username" and "pro". "pro" is the attribute that has so many quotes inside it

Comment: No you can not. Thus, your provided json is not valid